# Go dev.boringcrypto branch - x/crypto library FIPS 140-2 compliance

Tags: go, encryption, cryptography, fips, boringssl

The `dev.boringcrypto` [branch of Go](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/dev.boringcrypto/misc/boring) replaces the built-in crypto modules with a FIPS-verified version:

> We have been working inside Google on a fork of Go that uses
> BoringCrypto (the core of [BoringSSL](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/)) for various crypto
> primitives, in furtherance of some [work related to FIPS 140-2](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp3678.pdf).
> We have heard that some external users of Go would be interested in
> this code as well, so this branch holds the patches to make Go use
> BoringCrypto.

Poking around through the source code, I can see the modifications to the low-level crypto code. However, the Go packages that I've been using all use the [`x/crypto` library](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/crypto), which I couldn't see any references to in the branch on first look. I would like some clarification around the suitability of this library in relation to FIPS 140-2 - if I compiled a project that uses `x/crypto` with a boringcrypto Go build, would the library become FIPS-compliant as well?

If this isn't the case - why not? If Go has a maintained FIPS-verified branch, why wouldn't a fundamental crypto library also have the same modifications?

Answer (score 2):

Once there is an active [CMVP](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program) (Cryptographic module validation programme), for the library you are using, then you can be assured of the FIPS 140-2 validation.

Remember, there are both "compliance" and "accreditation" concepts spoken about in relation to FIPS.

"Compliance" is where the underlying cipher is on the list of approved cryptographic primitives, i.e. `AES256-CBC`.

"Accreditation/Validation" is where the underlying library has been specifically audited by a NIST approved lab.

It's the latter you must rely upon for FIPS 140-2 production use (FedRAMP etc).

Looks like [CMVP #3753](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Module-Validation-Program/Certificate/3753) is what you need.

Any modification to the parameters underlying the certificate invalidates the accreditation.

Comment: Thanks. This is more of a Go question - BoringSSL, which the dev.boringcrypto branch is based off, is [validated](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/master/crypto/fipsmodule/FIPS.md). What I want to know is if the `x/crypto` library performs it's own cryptography, or if it uses the underlying boringSSL module without making any modifications (and nullifying the validation)

Comment: The simple way to test is run the lib and try and use non-FIPS crypto... say blake2, or curve25519 or whatever... the core of FIPS is that it shouldn't let you if the lib is in FIPS mode.